# Why to declare variable in the class, even assigning that variable to this in the constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the code below, as you can see I declared a variable `constObj` in the `Test` class. And at the same time assigning `constObj` object to `this` in the constructor.

Why do we need to declare the variable again, even though we already assigning it to `this` in the constructor?

In the `webstorm` IDE, it is throwing error `doesn't have the property constObj`, if I do `this.constObj`, if the variable is not declared. But the code is working fine without issues.

Is declaring the variable mandatory, even if we are assigning that to `this`

```js
const constObj = {
  a: function() {
    console.log("sivakumar");
  }
};

class Test {
  constObj: any; // Is this line mandatory? I mean declaring it???

  constructor() {
    Object.assign(this, {
      constObj
    });
  }

  callMethod() {
    this.constObj.a();
  }
}

new Test().callMethod();
```

Please let know, what will happen, if we don't declare.

Comment: Webstorm would probably recognize it if you did `this.constObj = constObj;` in the constructor

Comment: @TKoL - For WebStorm, but not for TypeScript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is declaring the variable is mandatory...

It's not a variable, it's a property.

**The answer for TypeScript**: Yes, it's mandatory, so that TypeScript knows that `Test` has that property for the purposes of doing its static type checks. (Note that the *way* you've done it is just one of the possible ways of declaring that property. But you do need to declare it.)

**The answer for JavaScript**: No, it's not mandatory¹, because JavaScript doesn't do static type checks.

---

¹ (and it's not possible per the *current* specification, but it [soon will be](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) and is commonly transpiled with tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io))